# Query String parameters in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a solution with a .aspx page inside a master page.I need to show a specific control in the .aspx page when I receive a parameter via query string.

Something like this:

http://localhost:20286/Sitio/Default.aspx?CategoryId=1298&OptionId=4

The second parameter is always null. I don´t understand why. Any idea?

```
var a = this.Page.Request.QueryString["CategoryId"]; // 1512
var b = this.Page.Request.QueryString["OptionId"];   // null
```

Comment: Are you printing a and b and seeing null? Can you include a little more code?

Comment: I'm able to access the query string just fine. Maybe we do need more code from you

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are passing OptionId to the child page?
For example, if it's a gridview, you need to include these in one of the columns:

```
DataNavigateUrlFields="OptionId" 
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/YourPage.aspx?OptionId={0}"
```

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the value is passed in OptionId.
The URL is formed to be sent in the body of an email. Once it reaches the other person, it opens the link: [link] (http://localhost:20286/Sitio/Default.aspx?CategoryId=1298&OptionId=4)

Answer (score 0):

Check Request.QueryString collection maybe it is a typo

Answer (score 0):

Please do verify if the query string is cleared/reset anywhere before this assignment is made.